# Vertical Page Layout Print Booklet Prints Does Not Print Correctly

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, booklet

I'm printing a duplexed booklet with vertical master spreads using the instructions by Cari Jansen (great tut) http://indesignsecrets.com/vertical-master-page-spreads.php/comment-page-1. But when I go to print, the pages will not print vertically. There must be a setting I'm missing or it not possible to print a calendar style booklet (duplexed - long side) using the Print Booklet plugin. There were a couple people that had the same issue but no answers to their question. Hopefully someone knows the answer.

[image: screenshot vertical spread layout preview error]

Answer (score 1):

A "booklet" is typically horizontal, not vertical. I don't think you can use the Print Booklet command to create a vertical booklet.

That being written, there is *nothing* stopping you from **adjusting the InDesign layout** and **rotating the page contents** (not the page) **90°CCW** and them printing it that way.

Comment: Thank you. Good workaround. Was just hoping the Print Booklet feature was able to generate a calendar/landscape style orientation but it looks like it does not.

Comment: @JudiWatanabe If this answer helped you, maybe you should mark it as "accepted" by clicking the diamond on the side.